# SSIS Passing Parameters from Master Package to Child to Data Flow Task

Tags: ssis, parameter-passing

I have been working with a co-worker in an attempt to setup a master and sub  SSIS package templates. These templates look into an audit table in order to identify the correct batch or create a new one. The start and end times of the batch are passed into the CDC (change data capture) table valued functions which returns the Start and END LSN's of the table.

This works by identifying the start and end dates of the batch in the master package. These dates then get set to user variables in the master package. The master package then calls a sub package and passes the  user variable start time as well as user variable end time to the sub packages package level parameters. At this point I can print or write the dates to a random table from the sub package and they are showing the correct values.

Next I want to add a data flow task that will use the sub packages package level parameters (Passed from master package) to run the table valued function for the correct time period. This should return the Start & End LSN's that can be used in the source query. Unfortunately what I am seeing is the Data Flow Task never executes any of the task inside the Data Flow. The Data Flow Task gets a nice green checkmark but if you open the dataflow none of the tasks have been executed.

We are scratching our heads on this one and have even created a simple proof of concept that passes a value from a master package to the sub and then attempts to print it from the sub packages DFT but it never executes.

Any ides what could be causing the data flow to be ignored but yet show a success status?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of headache and frustration I finally found the answer, or rather my co-worker. In the past I have always created stand alone packages that get called from a job in SSMS. When developing individual packages I typically add either a Data Conversion or Derived Column component at the end of the last step completed in the Data Flow. I then setup a data viewer on the path to the Data Conversion/Derived Column. This allows me to check the data before moving on to the next piece of the data flow.

I was using this tactic when working with a master package that calls the child package I was working on. This was the source of the problem. When the master package calls the child package it identifies that components in the Data Flow are not used later in the package and skips them.

**To summarize:** If you are using a master package to call a child package make sure all pieces of the Data Flow are used later on in the package or they will be skipped during processing.

Comment: What do you mean by "make sure all pieces of the Data Flow are used"? My Data Flows should be used but I think they aren't (my use is the same as yours I think). If I execute the child package on its own, the data flows get green ticks, if I execute the child package via its parent, I don't get the green ticks.